# JQuery FadeIn does not work in Ajax Success when page first loaded

Tags: jquery

When the page is first loaded, and the Ajax call is first made the FadeIn does not work inside my success function. The other Jquery functions do effect however DO work ie AddClass, HTML, Delay, Hide. However, once the page is loaded, any subsequent Ajax calls the FadeIn does work ... that is until the page is refreshed, when once again the FadeIn does not work first time. What am I doing wrong ? Thanks !

Html

`<div class="updated_comment"></div>`

```
<button type="button" id="update_comment" class="btn btn-primary">ONLY Update Comments</button>
```

JQuery:

```
    $("#update_comment").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var comment = $(".edit_comment").val();
    var $id = $("#reference").val();
    $.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        type: "POST",
        url: 'update_comment/'+$id,
        data: {edit_comment:comment},
        success: function () {

            $(".updated_comment").addClass("alert alert-success");
             $(".updated_comment").html("The Comment Has Been Updated").fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).hide(2000);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('there has been a system level error - please contact support')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any CSS applied to `.updated_comment` that would affect it's display, height, etc. ?

Comment: fadeIn and hide again... `fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).hide(2000)` ??

Comment: @BrianGlaz No css is added after display or before.

Comment: Where did you set the id `#update_comment` ? Where is the element with that id? I wonder why anything happens after you click.

Comment: @bipen I'm new to JQuery. I want the alert to gently appear. Remain visible for  1 second, then gently disappear. so, perhaps I have the wrong effects??

Comment: @EdwardBlack #update_comment is the ID of the button.

Comment: What is the initial css for `.updated_comment`?

Comment: @Vince, which button? There is no such button in your code.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Just added btn html

Comment: ok make sense :)... Does it hides the `div` when you load the page for first time?

Comment: why did he used a $ to initialise `var $id = $("#reference").val();`? Does this make any difference to var id = $("#reference").val();`???

Comment: @EdwardBlack No, it does not. Its a variable name so it can be anything. Most of the time, developer use `$` in front just to know that its a jquery object(not in this case though :) ) and that is it. No diffrence. It depends on opinion, either you want to have one in front or not doesn't matter

Comment: Thank you, i was wondering for a long time.

Comment: @marzelin Sorry I didn't see your comment until now. There is no specific css around the class updated_ comment. However, Bootstrap is used through the page..

Answer (score 0):

Call the code on document ready.
You can solve the fadeIn -> delay -> fadeOut by using `setTimeout`.

Also you are missing a semicolon after the `alert`.

**Html**

```
<div class="updated_comment"></div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#update_comment").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var comment = $(".edit_comment").val();
        var $id = $("#reference").val();
        $.ajax({
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            type: "POST",
            url: 'update_comment/'+$id,
            data: {edit_comment:comment},
            success: function () {

                $(".updated_comment").addClass("alert alert-success");

                 $(".updated_comment").html("The Comment Has Been Updated");
                 $(".updated_comment").fadeIn(1000);

                 setTimeout(function(){
                     $(".updated_comment").fadeOut(1000);
                 },1000);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('there has been a system level error - please contact support');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Many thanks !   However, I get the same result. When page first load, no fade in. Then subsequent Ajax calls work great.

Comment: My Ajax call is held in a separate file, which has a $(document).ready on it.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else in your code, in a part which you don't show.

Comment: The $ on $id is of no importance and has no impact on the code. It is a convention I followed out of a tutorial book when creating vars.

Comment: Is it possible that the code is not working, because you are missing a semicolon after the `alert`?

Comment: semicolon in javascript doesn't really matters ... :).. that shouldn't be a case

Comment: Are you sure? I made another experience with that. My code even stops working if i leave out a semicolon after "console.log()"

Comment: after the alert ?  you mean here : 
$(".updated_comment").addClass("alert alert-success");

To my knowledge you don't add semie colons between each class.

Comment: I mean the alert function inside the error callback function. `alert('there has been a system level error - please contact support');`

Comment: Added the semi colon after the alert, and it made no difference.  Essentially the problem is that the fadeIn effect is not loading on first page load, but it Does load on after a succesfull click.

Comment: Im not sure what your goal is, do you want the fadeIn to be triggered automaticaly after the page was loaded first, or do you only want it to trigger after the button click?

Comment: I want the alert to fade in when the btn is clicked and the Ajax call is executed. then, after 1 sec, it fades out.  That's it.   The problem is that when the page is loaded the First click on the btn will not fire the fadein, it only fires it on subsequent clicks of the btn ie no fresh page load.

Comment: Now i understand what you try. Well the problem is that you did not explained your problem good enough, thats probably why most of the potential helpers did not answered. I would suggest you delete the question and ask it again, but this time explain better what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to trigger the click function on document load. Since all of our effect is taking place inside a click event, it doesn't work on page load unless you trigger the click

Add this to your ready function before/after the above function:

```
 $("#update_comment").trigger('click');
```

or call the click function as soon as you register the event.

```
 $("#update_comment").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    ......
  }).click();
```

Comment: I did as you requested, trying both methods, and in both cases, the alert fires the moment the page loaded prior to any button click.

Comment: So the problem is that your ajax is fired even though you never pressed the button? And then it calls the error callback function?

Comment: @Vince ok wait. You want the fade in to work only in button click or also in first load of the document?

Comment: @bipen I only want the fade in to work when the there #update_comment btn is clicked and the Ajax call has been success.   I do not want the fade in to work on first page load.

Comment: ok crap then my answer is all wrong. :):) ... Anyways this is getting interesting. So you mean to say when you click on the button(first time), the fade in doesn't work right?

Comment: @bipen Yes - exactly. fadeIN does not work on first page load, with first button click but DOES work on every successive click.